# Excel playoff bracket

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've created a playoff bracket and want to setup a way to automatically move the team name to the next round (another cell) once 4 wins are achieved. I'm using Excel 2010. 
Example:
Compare the value in C3 and C5. Whichever equals 4 then the value/text in B3 or B5 is moved to D4 and so on for the duration of the playoff bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there's a better way of accomplishing this but a rudimentary nested IF statement works fine:

```
=IF(C3=4, B3, IF(C5=4, B5, ""))
```

The formula checks C3 first, then if that's not 4 it checks C5, if that isn't 4 either then it's simply blank.

[image: Example of nested IF formula]